# PHP arrays and memory allocation

Tags: php, arrays, memory

Random question that crossed my mind:
If I define an array in PHP like so:

```
$arr = Array();
$arr[7392171] = "some value";
```

How is this stored internally? Does it map the key 7392171 to "some value", or does it work like JavaScript and put 7392170 empty values before it?
I'm guessing it's the former, because indexed and associative arrays are the same (at least from my understanding) and comparable to objects in JavaScript.
So yeah, just wondering :)

Comment: Why do you think JavaScript puts 7392170 empty values before it???

Comment: Because: `var arr = []; arr[7392171] = "some value";` If you view that array now, you get `,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, (massive number of commas) ,,,,,,,,,,,"some value"` - that's why.

Comment: Oh, and because after that assignment, `arr.length` returns 7392171.

Comment: where's the "not even wrong" button?

Comment: @Kolink JavaScript hasn't created the elements - for example, if you do for(i in arr) { console.log(i) } it will only report the single key. The problem is that an ECMASCript array expects to be an ordered list, but you're treating it like an object, so .length reports the incorrect count. FYI, whatever you're using to view the commas is using the same faulty assumption.

Comment: Ah, okay. I assumed that because IE Dev Tools, Chrome Inspector, Firebug and all their alert() functions responded with commas to mark "empty" indices.

Comment: You can test this in an interactive console with `php -a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

test it with `var_dump($arr)`

if it created 739217 empty values you will see it :)

cheers :)

Comment: Ehe, of course. Should've realised that. Also by the fact that `Array(1 => "a", 2 => "b")` and `Array(2 => "b", 1 => "a")` are different. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

All arrays are stored associatively in PHP.  Key names need not have any connection to its order.

Side question - This is done by hash map i guess?